Kafka producers fail to send after kafka brokers are brought down then up
The Kafka producers in my application fail to write messages to Kafka after Kafka brokers are brought down then up.
Instead, this keeps getting printed:
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 17 record(s) for test-topic-5:179287 ms has passed since batch creation

Once I restart the application, the Kafka producer is able to send messages successfully again. What is the reason send fails even though the brokers are brought back up? How do I get send to succeed without having to restart the application?
